# how to get user's screen resolution with PHP

Tags: php, screen, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)

well the question is self explanatory

where i want to reach is

```
$width = ; //user screen width in here
```

F1! F1!

Comment: Although you cannot strictly detect the resolution of the User's environment, but based on the User Agent string, you can guess with reasonable accuracy the class (mobile/tablet/desktop) of the device used. Check out http://mobiledetect.net/ .

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need JavaScript, not PHP.

```
var screenWidth = window.screen.width,
    screenHeight = window.screen.height;
```

You can then send it to the server via Ajax (with an `XmlHttpRequest`).

See also the [MDC `window.screen` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen).

Comment: can you share a sample code for sending it to php variable via AJAX?

Answer (score 9):

You can't, not in php. PHP is strictly server-side.

Comment: geez.... why do i forget this fact....

Comment: HI, I understand. But info like browser type,vendor and prefered languages etc. which we can access from `$_SERVER` variable. For eg: `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` like this for language. Even though it is server side language and execution, still we can get info like this from client. I wonder the screen size also should be provided, but i know it is not in current generation may be in future they can add.@Femaref

Comment: Those are http headers. Http is used to access webpages, but that's not the only thing it does. It's a standard for data transmission, as such, things like screen space (which is something of concern after the data arrives at the client is cosmetic) does not have a place in the http standard.

Comment: What are you talking about? You can't get the clients resolution in php, as php isn't executed on the client.

Answer (score 5):

you can't get it server-side, you have to get it client-side with javascript with innerWidth. you can pass it to the server-side with AJAX if you need to.

Comment: why negative? it is as relevant as the accepted answer, and I answered before Matt did.

Comment: ok, so innerWidth doesn't work in IE until IE9. forgot about that. I'll take my downvote and shut up now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript. Get the user's screen, send it to the server and get it by php.

Comment: can you post a sample of how to send data to server php file via ajax?"