# How fill IMG src with JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have this function in `PHP`, which came in a project that I' working:

```
  foreach ($reports["included_reports"] as $index => $report_name ) {
    if (! in_array( $report_name, $reports["excluded_reports"])) {
      $optional_reports .= 
      "<div class=\"large-12 columns\">
         <div class=\"panel\">
           <a href=\"./graph_all_periods.php?$graph_args&amp;g=". $report_name ."&amp;height=???&amp;width=???\">
             <img BORDER=0 style=\"padding:2px;\" $additional_cluster_img_html_args title=\"$cluster_url\" SRC=\"./graph.php?$graph_args&amp;g=". $report_name ."&amp;height=???&amp;width=???\" >
           </a>
         </div>
       </div>";
   }
 }
```

I would like to resize the image to fill my div, but I cannot use `width:100%` 'cause I have to inform the `width` and `height` to PHP. But PHP is executed first and I can't know the resolution of user monitor either. Searching in Google I found out [I only can know the user monitor resolution via JavaScipt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180134/how-to-get-users-screen-resolution-with-php).
So I wonder if is possible to do something that I can know the user monitor and inform to my `width` and `heigh` parameters in `img` tag.

Comment: does the height=???&width=??? have to be filled? Otherwise you can use jquery to resize the image

Comment: @StephanusYanaputra, The problem is that the `img` is generated by a `graph.php` and there I have to inform the size.

Comment: @ValterHenrique though you need to specify the size in graph.php, you still shouldn't need to set it in the img tag here

Comment: @MrGlass, yes, but I would like to inform the size of `width` just like if was `width: 100%` to `graph.php`, not inform the absolute value in `graph.php` 'cause there is many different size of monitors and my `div` is defined to be `width=100%` already.

Comment: @ValterHenrique best way to ensure that is to set it as a background image and use CSS background-size to stretch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to ensure that an image will always fill a div to set it as a background image and use CSS background-size to stretch it

Answer (score 0):

In your js, for the user monitor try `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`. For the image dimensions, you can use 100% in your css and then get the height and width with your js in px with `img.clientWidth`.