# how to trigger html/php file base on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, screen-resolution

i am developing one wordpress responsive website. but now i am facing problem menu issue. please see the bellow image for my navigation. on top black bar **"Check our Town"** will have drop down menu and on blue bar **About Us** also have drop down menu

[image]

so i want when screen resolution bellow 800 then top menu and logo part will be different. i know one way like i can make separate header part then hide it via css and call it via css media query. for that i need to keep that code always in body. but i don't want it i want it will code will be in body only when it required.

say if make top area separate html/php file if i can call it when screen resolution will 800/480 etc that would be work i guess. i can be possible thru php/js but i have no idea how.

see the image there is two part for navigation one is black area and another is blue area. when i will be bellow 800px it will be all menu in one drop down.

see bellow menu i want this type when screen resolution bellow 800px

[image]

Comment: How about Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180134/how-to-get-users-screen-resolution-with-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu So Bootstrap is the new jQuery now? OP: try using existing elements. Can you scale your logo down with CSS? Could you use a sprite?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu thanks .. i am not expart on bootstrap but i think bootstrap can not include two nav to one drop dwon i think the way i want for that i need to seperate.. but i am not sure.. idea welcome

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend the ajax to load the 2 navs. Its adding an extra http request, which is slower than just giving both desktop and mobile the little bit of extra markup required.

I think using media queries is your best approach.

This is what i think you're trying todo:
http://jsfiddle.net/krismeister/CNr5y/

The relevevant portion is the 
`@media screen and (min-width:800px){`

Comment: thanks. yes if i can not do anyother way then media query i will use.. but personally i don't add extra those code on body.

Comment: heres one with no extra markup:
http://jsfiddle.net/krismeister/CNr5y/1/
it uses nav:before to add any mobile content.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve it is to use ajax. Send an empty page to a client, check window size, and request the content via ajax with a screen width as a param.

Comment: i have no problem to call via ajax but i don't know yet how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i am not so good on jquery and json.. do you bellow way can work ?

```
$(function() {
    $.post('some_script.php', { width: 800px }, function(json) {
        if(json.outcome == 'success') {
           header-800px.php;
        } else {
            header.php;
        }
    },'json');
});
```

ref :[Getting the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)