# how to PHP if condition with browser width?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, browser

I have some script like below but it does not work

```
<?php
$width = "<script>document.write(window.outerWidth);</script>";
$width2 = (int)$width;
echo $width2;
if ( $width2 < 800 ) { ?>
    bad
<? } else { ?>
    ok
<? } ?>
```

please help me ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Comment: php is run on the server, so the screen width can't possibily be available to it, you'd need javascript, or if your doing css based on screen size, media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need JavaScript (taken from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180134/how-to-get-users-screen-resolution-with-php` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php`)

```
var screenWidth = window.screen.width,
    screenHeight = window.screen.height;
You can then send it to the server via Ajax (with an XmlHttpRequest).
```

See also the [MDC window.screen docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen)

Answer (score 0):

You mixed JavaScript and PHP.

```
<script>document.write(window.outerWidth);</script>
```

You cannot execute that JavaScript in PHP.

If you what to get browser width, you have to write a JavaScript and put it into browser to execute. The JavaScript should sent the size to server by AJAX/form post.