# Wordpress & Enquire.js - conditional loading philosophy

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, enquire.js

Is not a matter of code, I just don't get the idea of how things works in this specific case.

I'm woking on a Wordpress theme which should dynamically load portions of php code through javascript.
It actually works combined with UA Sniffing because if the device is mobile, the mobile template should be used anyway but that's not the point.

- If the screen.width is < 1080px the Mobile version menu of my Wordpress theme should be loaded.
- otherwise, if the screen.width is bigger, the desktop menu version should be loaded
- a solution based just on CSS Media queries is not acceptable since the desktop version is too heavy.

So I decided to conditional dynamically load content through [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)
The first part of my WP-homepage-template.php is:

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:1080px)", {
<script type="text/javascript">
    match : function() {
        $("body").load(
          "/path/headernav-phone.php"
        );

    unmatch : function() {
            $("body").load(
          "/path/headernav-desktop.php"
        );
    }
}
```

So, when the size of the screen hits 1080px, Wordpress should to load headernav-phone.php
which contains just a wp_nav_menu(MOBILE) call.
If the screen size is bigger, Wordpress loads headernav-desktop.php which includes wp_nav_menu(DESKTOP).

This doesn't work:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_nav_menu() in /XX/YYY/ZZZ/webseiten/XXX.YY/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/templates/headernav-phone.php on line 14

It looks like that my code is run before the CMS, and it breaks its own functions.

Comment: Are you enqueuing enquire.js in the footer? or is it loading before the <body> tag?

Comment: Atm is placed in the head section through wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Which WP version? Have you tried disabling plugins one by one checking the error?

Comment: yes, everything disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the logic is flawed.
For one, [there's no way to detect the screen width with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504459/1287812).

Secondly, if you were to generate a PHP -> JS file (`my-script.js.php`), [you'd have to load WordPress engine two times](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54583/12615).
<sub>*The Answer in this link is *super-pro*. You'll find easier methods that use `wp-load.php` and `WP_USE_THEMES`.*</sub>

Thirdly, the way you're trying to load a theme template would require the *"load two times"* approach. Or [**solving it with AJAX**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106436/12615) and `wp_localize_script`.

If I understood the Question correctly, I think the best bet would be to use [WordPress user-agent detection](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) and [enqueue your scripts and styles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) accordingly. Study the [core function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/vars.php#L101) to adapt to your needs.

**[update]**

Still not sure if all this complexity is really needed. Would something like this work in a generic `header.php`?

```
if( wp_is_mobile() )
    wp_nav_menu(MOBILE);
else
    wp_nav_menu(DESKTOP);
```

But, if you really need this changes to happen dynamically, then AJAX would be the choice.

Comment: Thank you Brasofilo, you answer sounds pro too. It seems like that atm there is no "clean" way of testing window.size to then call an optimised wp-function (like wp_menu in my case). In this scenario do CSS media queries remains the only way?

Comment: Well, I've learned a lot from that wizard ;) I really don't have a precise Answer as I'm not understanding what do you need to load at what moment. What does `headernav-phone.php` contains? Is it a simple `wp_nav_menu(MOBILE)`? Would it need to load specific CSS and JS files? If possible, [add more details](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18435815/edit) to the Question.

Comment: Updated the Answer, does it shed some light?