# Why is my JavaScript output echoing empty spaces?

Tags: javascript, php

When I try this, it will show some spaces or new lines in output, i want to parse or empty spaces and new lines in output:

```
<?php
$inner_width = "<script>document.write(innerWidth);</script>";
if($inner_width < 800){
   $hashtag = '#focus'; 
}else{
   $hashtag = ''; 
}
?>
<a href='mywebsite/items.php?cat=2<?php $hashtag; ?>'>Item 2</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that php file has not spaces, or lines before `<?php` tag or after `?>`? You can remove `?>` tag at end

Comment: Please reformulate, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I added an picture

Comment: Why you don't use `document.getElementById('IdYourTag').innerHTML = 'Your Content...'` and print inside a tag?. it's a little weird use `document.write()` because **If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML** [Check](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp).

Comment: The spaces are almost certainly not being generated by `document.write()` but are a consequence of how your PHP file is formatted.

Comment: i want to use (if) statement, ex: if($inner_width > 800){echo 'g';}else{echo 'l';}

Comment: `trim()` function? Also, maybe an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: if($inner_width > 800){
//something
}else{//something} thank you. trim() not work for both js and php in my code

Comment: I still don't understand why you're mixing JS and PHP. The only thing the PHP is doing is echoing out a `<script>` which the browser will execute. Why not just use JS for this? If you explain the bigger picture, maybe we could help. See the 2 responses in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19291236/296555. This one might be more useful to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Comment: @waterloomatt please see my update answer. i hope you understand me, thanks

Comment: What does this `$inner_width < 800` -> `"<script>document.write(innerWidth);</script>" < 800` even mean?

Comment: 800 mean: 800 Screen Pixel.

Comment: @Aso You are comparing a string (`$inner_width = "<script>document.write(innerWidth);</script>"`) to a number (`800`). This won't work. Also your code is short/incomplete. Your problem is not reproducible. I don't understand why people are upvoting/faving this question...

Comment: @akinuri you know, my question is about my experience, so if you want to help me, you can write some idea for me. I didn't understand what I'm doing

Comment: Looks like you're trying to make conditional links based on the screen size. Why? What are you trying to do? Are you trying to determine who is using a phone? Give us _more details about your overall goal_.

Comment: @waterloomatt My script doesn't work, I want to fix it.

Comment: @Aso - As it stands, your question doesn't make much sense. I've asked you repeatedly for more details. If you don't know what you want, how can we? So again, ignoring the coding language, what are trying to do?