# Counter change based on device width

Tags: php

I have using this php code for add clearfix div `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after 6 item in sequence. & it is working fine.

Here, I want to set Counter according to device width. that means, if, device width is more than 1024. So, Counter will calculate 6(add clearfix div after 6 item). & if device width is less than 1024 So. Counter will calculate 4(add clearfix div after 4 item).

I have this code:
**I have this code:**

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>

<div class="item"></div>
<?php 
        if(++$counter % 6 === 0) { ?>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php  
        }
    } 
    ?>
```

**It would look like this:**

**if device width is > 1024**

```
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
```

**if device width is < 1024**

```
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
```

Some help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can't detect screen width with PHP : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php You need some Javascript to do that. (Or explain the purpose of your code to find another way to achieve your goal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP runs on server. it doesn't know about the client machine width. 
howerver JS can get the width of the screen. so here is some trick to solve this

**Step1:** store width in cookie by JS on client machine when user comes on site by this code

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
document.cookie="screen_width="+w;
```

**Step2:** Now get cookie in php when needed the width of the screen

```
$screen_width = $_COOKIE['screen_width'];
```

**Step3:** Now you can use this width in your php code in the condition

```
<?php 
    $counter = 0;
    $screen_width = $_COOKIE['screen_width'];

    $limit = 4;
    if($screen_width>1024)
    {
        $limit = 6;
    }

    foreach ($categories as $category){
?>  
    <div class="item"></div>
        <?php 
        if(++$counter % $limit === 0) 
        { 
        ?>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php  
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: nice way but for the `1st visit` there wont be any cookie named `screen_width` since server side execution takes place first and html is served which sets the cookie. `if its an ajax request it will work in such case too.`

Comment: ya we can do like that

Answer (score 1):

You can use this javascript code

`<script>
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.className = 'item';
    var cfDiv = document.createElement('div');
    cfDiv.className = 'clearfix';
    var myWidth=screen.width;
    if(myWidth>=1024)
    {
       for(i=1; i<=2; i++)
       {
          for(j=1; j<=6; j++)
          {
               document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
          }
          document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(cfDiv);
       }
    }
    else
    {
       for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
       {
          for(j=1; j<=4; j++)
          {
               document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
          }
          document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(cfDiv);
       }
    }
</script>`

I think this will work.

happyCoding :D

Answer (score 0):

Actuualy you would need to use `javascript` property `screen.width` and `screen.height`.Php cannot make any role in this.

See more answers and the opinions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)