# How to add parameter to image url with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, url-parameters

I can embed images on my page with specified width and height (like this: `<img src="image.php?w=100&h=100">`)

I want to load different image sizes depending on device screen width:
100x100 for screen widths lower than 600px and 200x200 in other cases. As I understand php knows nothing about user screen so I have to use JS.

This didn't work:

```
<img src="image.php?<script>document.write('w=100&h=100')</script>">
```

That worked:

```
<script>document.write('<img src="image.php?w=100&h=100">')</script>
```

Is that a correct way for doing this? Any consequences I should take into consideration?

Comment: Do you have to do this server side? You could always use dynamic CSS (via Javascript) on the client side. The upshot is the you wouldn't have to generate and store a bunch of images server side.

Comment: There's a new HTML5 element called `picture` that you might be interested in, but it's still a long way away from full browser support. Until then, a JavaScript solution is probably your best bet. [Article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/) and [current browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture)

Comment: It is possible in server side because you can put custom param here. https://gradindesign.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/1_wlz32vkptgjya9xlzj0w6g.jpeg?w=499, if you download the image, it will has the same width/height you specified. You can also try to inspect element and see that smaller image will has smaller load size too. I'm still looking how wordpress do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that code. But I think that bst way is to change src of images on the server side.

```js
function addParams(w, h) {
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("img.withParams");
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        img[i].src = img[i].src + "?w=" + w + "&h=" + h;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    addParams(10, 10);
})
```

```html
<img class="withParams" src="img.php"/>    
<img src="img.php" />    
<img class="withParams" src="img.php" />
```

Comment: How can I do it on server side if I don't know user's screen resolution

Comment: @Tigrokon You can se this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)