# Calculate characters that fit to screen PHP

Tags: php

how would you calculate number of characters that fits to screen (and possibly just in one table field) in PHP?
Thanks a lot, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: First figure out how wide screen is (if that is even possible in PHP), then figure out how wide one character is (monospace fonts are your friend), third divide the one by the other

Comment: It is not possible to get the screen resolution just with PHP. You would need JavaScript for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Comment: Thank you for ideas, my current problem is how to determine character width...