# How to function to get current (window)screen size using js and php

Tags: javascript, php

I have find the way to print current window size with using js and php but when i execute with function it won't works. Any one please help.

`<?php $currentwidth = " <script>document.write(window.innerWidth); </script>";
echo $currentwidth; //works fine but belowis not working
if ( $currentwidth <= "480" ) { echo "TRUE"; } else { echo "FALSE"; }; ?>`

Comment: you should use jquery post, and with it post values to the php file

Comment: Javascript is a client side script. Php is server side scripts. In this case you can not assign JS result to php

Comment: Like I said in my incorrect answer, this post can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up javascript and php. javascript runs in browser and php runs in server. If you want php to print something you have to send the value to the server.