# Remove sidebar (not to hide) in wordpress if screen size < 500px

Tags: wordpress, screen, media, sidebar

Is it possible to Remove sidebar in wordpress if screen size < 500px, else shows up.

I have this in single.php:

```
<?php get_sidebar('left'); ?>
```

And my sidebar-left.php is:

```
<div class="sidebar-left">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar1') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use css media query:

```
@media (max-width:500px) {
  .sidebar-left {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fjodor, but I forgot to specify that I want to remove the sidebar, not to hide. Sorry my mistake! :P

Comment: @IustinBeceneagă Why would you want to remove it completly instead of just hiding it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Use css media queries:

   ```
   @media (max-width: 500px) {
     .sidebar-left {
       display: none;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use jQuery:

   ```
   if ($(window).width() < 500) {
       $( ".sidebar-left" ).remove();
   }
   ```

It is not possible to prevent Wordpress (on server-side) to generate the sidebar html code, because Wordpress does not have information about the width of your browser window. You can read more about this 'Problem' here: 
[Getting the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility which I'm not 100% sure it does what you need, but you could remove it in general for mobile devices.

Wordpress has the function  **wp_is_mobile()**, so you can create a condition to not call the sidebar if the user is coming from a mobile device - which usually have the smaller screens.

It should look something like this:

```
<?php 
  if (!wp_is_mobile() ) {
  // if device is not mobile get sidebar
       get_sidebar('left'); 
  }
?>
```

Like that you would only show the sidebar when the user is not coming from a mobile device.

Here is the wordpress the function reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

Edit:
Also be aware that if you change it in single.php you only change it for the view of a single post. Otherwise I think you would also need to edit page.php for page views and so on..