# Adding "Media query" to If/else statements in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, responsive-design, media-queries

Im using the following code to echo content in wordpress based on the size of its title.

```
<?php 
$title  = the_title('','',false);
if(strlen($title) > 35):
    echo content(20);
else:
    echo content(45);
endif;
?>
```

Is there a simple way of projecting a media query before this to echo an output based on the window width so basically for mobiles and devices

As per a reply i still cant get this to work using:

```
<?php 
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    echo content (20);
} else {
$title  = the_title('','',false);
if(strlen($title) > 35):
    echo content(20);
else:
    echo content(45);
endif;
}
?>
```

Even simplifying the code to following doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php 
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    echo content(20);
} else {
    echo content(45);
}
?>
```

and simply uses the "else" value: echo content(45) on mobile

Comment: i think thats right way

Comment: thanks for the quick comment but you misunderstood my question. ID like to basically add:
   if($windowwidth) > 480;
echo "this"

Comment: What didn't work for you? What are input and expecting output?

Comment: Determining the output based on the "size" of the_title works fine. Its the wp_is_mobile that is not outputting as intended its basically ignoring the wp_is_mobile

Comment: Did you try it on real mobile devices or just resize your browser?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress doesn't have any functionalities to detect window width. PHP itself [cannot do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php).

The most promising solution is to use [wp_is_mobile()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/):

```
if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
    echo "this";
} else {
    echo "that";
}
```

Comment: so in theory this should work?

      `<?php 
      if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
       echo content (20);
      } else {
       $title  = the_title('','',false);
       if(strlen($title) > 35):
           echo content(20);
       else:
           echo content(45);
       endif;
      }
      ?>`

Comment: sorry about the formatting ive added it at the bottom of the question to clarify