# How to setup an if statement for different Media to change a variable

Tags: php, media-queries

This is what I want:
$Variable = 3;
I want to change this number to a 1 on a mobile

So I was hoping to do something like this:

```
if ((@media only screen and (min-width:481px)) or (@media only screen and (min-width:981px)){ $Variable = 3; } else $Variable = 1;
```

I'll try to explain;

When changing from an iPad or desktop screen size I want the value of the variable to change from 3 to 1. Thats why I was hoping to use an if statement.

Is this possible? Or do i need to use css in some way? 
Any help welcome

Comment: Css cannot remove columns, only make them invisible. You could use the table selectors and remove the columns using `display: none;`

Comment: This is not for a column i just called the variable column. All i want to do is change the value of the variable in different media

Comment: Ohh you're trying to do this by using PHP. You can't.

Comment: See this [Getting the screen resolution using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)