# Resize an image according to screen width in YII

Tags: php, yii

I am doing a **[php](/questions/tagged/php)** project using **[yii](/questions/tagged/yii)**.

I want to resize an image according to user's device.

I am using this code segment to render image:

```php
if($deal->imageBin)
    app()->controller->worklet('deal.slideshow',array('deal' => $deal, 'scaleTo'=>300));
```

`'scaleTo'` is a variable for enter width manual, but I want to use value from device screen width.

can do this using jquery?

Comment: I do not know yii list of functions, so maybe something already in there, but I just would not know. One cannot, of course, acquire screen width via php, so maybe go the route of something along the lines of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504526/797620 or the code further down that page http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421797/797620 and use that to pass into your yii `scaleTo` variable.

Comment: can i directly assign to php variable ?

Comment: one is server side the other is client side. if you wanted a pure php method, perhaps go the route of using https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php and creating an abosolutely insane amount of `switch()` checks, each with their own xy sizes, and hope you can at least get somewhat accurate. Total hack job though. Not something I would want to do.