# display php variable with a value in specific window width

Tags: php, variables

I want to display a php variable in a specific window width.

Example:

In my `HTML` I have `<div class="scount"></div>` with no content.

I'd like to display `<?php $sumcount=3; ?>` as a content on `scount` div element on a width that is greater than 768 else display `<?php $sumcount=1; ?>` that is less than 768

Please help, I badly need your cooperation. :)

Comment: This isn't something to be solved with PHP; this is something to be solved with a CSS framework.  Look into bootstrap or foundation.

Comment: Ahh okay, but could you please add samples because I'm not that an expert on php

Comment: I didn't, although it deserves it.  This question has nothing to do with PHP.  It is a question about something on the browser side.  By the time the browser renders it, the PHP is done.  You need to be looking at a CSS and/or AJAX solution.

Comment: ahh right ajax, thanks Tim... I have looking some samples but can't understand how to implement this on ajax

Comment: AJAX is the most accessible way to get information back to the server where PHP lives.  You'll have to use javascript to determine screen size (assuming javascript will do that; I don't know), send that information back to the server, and then have the server send the content that you can then have the browser display.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect what device is being used then you should examine

```html
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

for clues.

Comment: Can you have some samples, so I can understand more? I'm quite new to php

Comment: @bellabelle this varialbe contains user's browser name.If it is browser from Android/IPhone device, then more likely width of device will less than 768px.

Comment: ahh okay, but still I'm searching some code on how to do this

Comment: No, this doesn't directly answer your question.  It may give you a clue to make a more educated **guess** about mobile, but it will not help you one little bit for desktop.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use CSS. Create two divs and have the CSS effect them based on screen size

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        div1 {
            display: block;
        }
        div2 {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        div1 {
            display: none;
        }
        div2 {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise if you need the screensize for PHP, you need to use JavaScript (AJAX)

Comment: Hello ezw, I've tried this and add php as a content on each div elements but the php code runs even i display it to none

Comment: PHP will run, but CSS will display the right div block due to screen size