# JavaScript returned string dos't work in PHP if

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

I have a problem with JS and PHP:

```
    <?php
       $hi = "<script>document.write('hi');</script>";
       if ($hi == "hi") {
          echo("ok");
       } else {
          echo("error");
       }
    ?>
```

I get "error"! What is the problem?

Comment: i think the script is not a tag, you can call javascript in  php, But i think you can't assign it as a string. I don't know much php, but if you log the $hi variable it will be string.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: you are mixing up serverside and client side programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS but <?php echo $hi; ?> works and print "hi"!

Comment: @AmirhosseinWP Because echo $hi prints the javascript code, that later will be executed by the browser to print 'hi'.

Comment: another dupe (based on the OP's comments under first answer): [Getting the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)

Comment: @AmirhosseinWP you can check the post. Please let me know if it worked for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

See the question [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).

PHP does not run your JS script at all -- only the browser will do that. Therefore, your `$hi` variable contains the entire script as a string, not the script's output. `$hi = "<script>document.write('hi');</script>";`.

If you want the output to be calculated before the page is sent to the browser, you would simply set `$hi = "hi";`, and then run your `if` check on it. There is no need for `document.write` in the server-side case.

Comment: but i need to get screen.width and check it in PHP.

Comment: [Getting the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)

Comment: @AmirhosseinWP so i think you need to execute the script first then pass the variable which holds the width value.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS but echo($hi); working and prints "hi"!

Comment: @AmirhosseinWP just let me check , i don't know the syntax. Will check and post the answer

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Thank you for your follow up.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know whether it can be written in a much better way, but i think this is how you can pass the variable from javascript and assign to a variable in php and you can check using an if else condition.

**Note**: the below code doesn't work in stack snippets. So check this link which is an online php editor [Here you can add the below code and run it](http://phpfiddle.org/).

Also check whether its proper to check with a string, i think you need to convert it to a number and check. like Number("1000") => 1000 in javascript.

I hope the below snippet will solve the issue.

```js
<script>
var p1 = screen.width;
</script>

<?php
$screenWidhFromJS = "<script>document.write(p1)</script>";
echo "Screen Width $screenWidhFromJS";
echo "<br>";
// your condition
if($screenWidhFromJS > "1000"){
 echo $screenWidhFromJS;
}else{
 echo "below 1000 screen width size";
}
?>
```

Comment: May i know whats the reason of a down vote? can you add the comment whats the issue