# How to display and submit one of two forms based on the screen size?

Tags: php, forms, responsive

I have 2 identical forms, one intended for desktop and the other for mobile. I use Bootstrap4 to display the appropriate form for the intended screen. Both forms submit data to the same processing PHP file. Since both forms have the same field names, only one form works. Is there a way to include() only the appropriate form using PHP based on screen size, so that there is no conflict between the 2 forms.

Comment: Get the screen size or other info using javascript, then create the form with javascript or redirect to the proper form generated by PHP.

Comment: this may help [Getting the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)