# How can i get browser info and device info from the end user?

Tags: php

Expected result should be
 1. You are browsing from   Chrome 75.0.3770.142 (Windows 10) 
 2. Your device has monitor res.  1366x768px ,  4-cores CPU .

Comment: The browser info is readily available from the [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable, but the rest cannot be retrieved with PHP. Javascript might be able to get the resolution, but the computer info would be tricky.

Comment: as this are client information, get them from the client, have a google for "js browser fingerprint" leading you e.g. fingerprint.js

Comment: js is the best solution for my query but is there any to find out through php.

Answer (score 0):

This might help! Using [get_browser()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125) will at least get you part of what you're looking for!

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($browser);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
function getBrowser() {
  $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $bname = 'Unknown';
  $platform = 'Unknown';
  $version= "";
  if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'linux';
  } elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'mac';
  } elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'windows';
  }
  if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) {
    $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
    $ub = "MSIE";
  } elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) {
    $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
    $ub = "Firefox";
  } elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) {
    $bname = 'Google Chrome';
    $ub = "Chrome";
  } elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) {
    $bname = 'Apple Safari';
    $ub = "Safari";
  } elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) {
    $bname = 'Opera';
    $ub = "Opera";
  } elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) {
    $bname = 'Netscape';
    $ub = "Netscape";
  }
  $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
  $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) . ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
  if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
  }
  $i = count($matches['browser']);
  if ($i != 1) {
    if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
      $version= $matches['version'][0];
    } else {
      $version= $matches['version'][1];
    }
  } else {
    $version= $matches['version'][0];
  }
  if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}
return array(
  'userAgent' => $u_agent,
  'name'      => $bname,
  'version'   => $version,
  'platform'  => $platform,
  'pattern'    => $pattern
  );
}

$browser = getBrowser();
print_r($browser);
```

Comment: I am working on it. So fat I have checked and found that It can only be possible with Javascript. But I am still working on it.

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Comment: Thanks i got screen specification through it.