# can't convert string to int from value was getting by javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

in my case I want to convert a string value to integer , the value was returned by a JavaScript code, but when i convert in i got, a type int(0) so the values wasn't converted correctly

can anyone help me please, thanks in advance

> this is the code

```
$screenwidth = "<script>document.write(screen.width);</script>";
var_dump($screenwidth);
var_dump((int)$screenwidth);
```

> this what i get as output

```
string(46)"1200"

int(0)
```

Comment: html script code won't run in php, so what happens is it tries to convert your html string into an integer.

Comment: See: [Getting the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504526)

Comment: There is no `1200` display. https://3v4l.org/ZlYGX please display actual results, or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed on the server, Javascript is sent from the server to the client, where it is then executed. You either want to:

- echo the script to the page (PHP will not have access to screen width)
  `echo "<script>document.write(screen.width);</script>";`
- make an ajax request to the server with the variable so that PHP can process it (PHP will be in a different context to when page was created) `<script>fetch(URL + "/index.php?width=" + screen.width);</script>`